# How to set Icon name on click

Tags: javascript, react-native

In header I add left component - icon, and I want to set icon on click. How can I do that?

I tried to set state value and return component that depends from this value.

```
<Header
            placement="left"
            leftComponent={  
              <Icon 
                name='keyboard-arrow-left'
                color='#ffffff'
                size={40}
                onPress={}
              />
            }
            centerComponent={<Text>User Info</Text>}
          />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create separate component for icon

```
export class MyIcon extends Component {
  state = { name: 'keyboard-arrow-left' }

  render() {
    return (
      <Icon 
        name={this.state.name}
        color='#ffffff'
        size={40}
        onPress={() => this.setState({ name: 'close' })}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

and use this component for `leftComponent` of your `Header`

```
<Header
  placement="left"
  leftComponent={  
    <MyIcon/>
  }
  centerComponent={<Text>User Info</Text>}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to fix this issue is to add a reference to your Icon component. Then use that reference to change any of the props of your icon.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.myIcon = ''; 
}

updateIconName = (nameEntered) => {
    this.myIcon.name = nameEntered;
}

render() {
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Header
                placement="left"
                leftComponent={  
                    <Icon 
                        name='keyboard-arrow-left'
                        color='#ffffff'
                        size={40}
                        onPress={this.updateIconName}
                        ref={(element) => {this.myIcon = element;}}
                    />
                }
                centerComponent={<Text>User Info</Text>}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```